# Tangent math node no longer has two values option

Tags: shader-nodes

I am trying to make an object to change colour depending on an angle in evee, and the only helpful topic I found had tangent nodes with multiple values

[image]

However, in my version blender, math node locks onto only 1 value when you change it to tangent, automatically disconnecting seperate xyz node.

[image]

What do I do? Why did they even change nodes like that?

Comment: AFAIK the second socket on your old tangent node didn't do anything anyway, see [eg](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/d38b4d4f2d8fa080200612597cf1d222549fde81/source/blender/nodes/shader/nodes/node_shader_math.c#L90-L97). Does the shader look different in the new version?

Comment: @scurest is correct, the second input does absolutely nothing when set to _Tangent_.

Comment: @scurest
Without the second socket it changes colour only when rotated X-wise, not both Y and X axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the second input. In earlier versions, the inputs of the *Math* node were not dynamic and didn't change in relation to the chosen function. But to quote the Blender Manual on the old *Math* node and especially the second value input:

- **Value**

  *Second numerical value. This value is not used in functions that accept only one parameter like the trigonometric functions, Round and Absolute.*

Since *Tangent* is a trigonometric function, it falls in the category of functions where the second input is not used. The tangent of $\theta$ can be calculated as:

$$\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$$

So even if you would try to calculate it using $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$, you would still only need one input value $\theta$. There is no variable which could make use of the second input value. And even regarding your question, the color should change depending on the viewing angle - which is just a single angle as well.